# Generate JSON dynamically from JAVA, Data type

Tags: javascript, java, json

I'm trying to generate a graph using `chart.js` and `Scatter.js` plugin

I'm having trouble generating the `JSON` to populate the graph.

What I need is:

```
var data3 = [
            {
                label: 'temperature',
                strokeColor: '#A31515',
                data: [
                    {
                        x: new Date('2011-04-11T11:45:00'),
                        y: 25
                    },
                    {
                        x: new Date('2011-04-11T12:51:00'),
                        y: 28
                    }
                ]
            }];
```

I am using:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("x", new Date(date));
            obj.put("y", Integer.valueOf(magnitud));
            listDentro.add(obj);
```

And I get:

```
var data3 = [
            {
                label: 'temperature',
                strokeColor: '#A31515',
                data: [
                        {'x':'2016-07-06T19:37:23.361-03:00','y':120},
                        {'x':'2016-07-06T15:57:45.762-03:00','y':120}]
            }];
```

I see the problem is that by using `obj.put ( "x", new Date (date));` the object is created Date and toString () returns.

I have not been able to achieve `x: new Date (stringFecha)`

Comment: That's not how you assign properties of an object.

Comment: This should've been one comment instead of 4, but I don't really care.

Comment: Is the only problem with the client-side `data3` structure that each `data` item's `x` property is a string instead of a `Date` object?

Comment: If so, why not just loop through that array and convert the strings to `Date` objects?

Comment: I've removed the 'charts' tag from your question because you're not really asking about charts, you're just asking about the data structure.

Comment: This should've been one comment instead of 4, but I don't really care.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to format a `Date`.
Consider [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
It formats dates.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to get the current date using Calendar and then formatting to my desired date format with SimpleDateFormat

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-dd-MM'T'hh:mm:ss");

obj.put("x", sdf.format(cal.getTime());
obj.put("y", Integer.valueOf(magnitud));
listDentro.add(obj);
```